# React redux connect with with styles and withrouter

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, router

I am trying to use connect in redux react as

Connect (mapstate.., mapdis..) (withstyles(dashboardstyle)(dashboard)

The above works fine but I need to add withRouter as well. 
Below change gives error 
Connect (mapstate.., mapdis..) (withstyles(dashboardstyle), withrouter(dashboard))

Whenever I add it gives exception such as cannot use class as a function. 
Any ideas how this can be fixed

Comment: We can help you much sooner if you provide a [mcve] which causes the exact error message which you are asking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to install recompose:

```
npm i -s recompose
```

Then in your component:

```
import compose from 'recompose/compose'


export default compose(
   withStyles(styles),
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(withRouter(Dashboard))
```

Answer (score 5):

What's the return value of `withStyles(styles)`?  I suspect it is a "Higher Order Component" (HOC), which is a function that expects to be passed the React component to wrap, and returns a React component. If that is the case, then you really want your call to look like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Dashboard))
)
```

That code is pretty ugly, though, and will rapidly get worse as you add in more HOCs, which is why the [Recompose suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823620/27561) is a much better way to go.  (But I wanted to add in some more context so that readers an understand what was causing the problem in the OP.)