# How to use refs in react through react-redux , withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use ref in a component connected to react-redux

I've tried this solution.

`connect(null, null, null, {forwardRef: true})(myCom)`

`<myCom ref={ref => this.myCom = ref} />`

this works just fine according to react-redux docs, but now when i try using

`withRouter` at the same time i get an error:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

so the final export code i have tried which lead to the above error

```js
export default connect(null, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(withRouter(withStyles(styles)(myCom)));
```

**Note**: withStyles doesn't cause any issues as i've tried removing only withRouter, the issue was resolved.

is there any solution to solve this issue ?

Comment: what does your myCom component look like?

Comment: @WillJenkins it's not a component issue, my component is class based component, i've just tested it now removed `withRouter` and `withStyles` and only left the first example i gave it worked fine. but when i use withRouter and withStyles i get an error. the issue here is to refer to the component it self, like if you tried to use ref without using `forwardRef: true` you need to refer the component that it's wrapped inside connect then withRouter then withStyles, i think this is the issue

Comment: possibly relevant: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10106

Comment: @WillJenkins i have update the question the issue relies only in withRouter

Comment: have you tried using compose? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823456/react-redux-connect-with-with-styles-and-withrouter?rq=1

Comment: @WillJenkins i'll look into it, to understand it more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to pass a ref to a component wrapped by `withRouter` you need to call it [wrappedComponentRef](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter/wrappedcomponentref-func). I recommend having `withRouter` as the outermost wrapper, so your example would look like the following:

```
withRouter(connect(null, null, null, {forwardRef: true})(myCom));
```

```
<myCom wrappedComponentRef={ref => this.myCom = ref} />
```

The following example and description are adapted from a related answer of mine: [Get ref from connected redux component withStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191025/get-ref-from-connected-redux-component-withstyles/57206665#57206665)

Below is code from a modified version of the [react-redux todo list tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial) that shows the correct syntax. I've included here the two files that I changed (TodoList.js and TodoApp.js), but the sandbox is a fully working example.

In `TodoApp`, I use the ref (via the `wrappedComponentRef` property) on `TodoList` to get and display its height. The displayed height will only get updated if `TodoApp` re-renders, so I've included a button to trigger a re-render. If you add a couple todos to the todo list, and then click the re-render button, you will see that the new height of the list is displayed (showing that the ref is fully working).

In `TodoList`, I'm using `withStyles` to add a blue border around the todo list to show that `withStyles` is working, and I'm displaying the primary color from the theme to show that `withTheme` is working. I am also displaying the `location` object from `withRouter` to demonstrate that `withRouter` is working.

`TodoList.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Todo from "./Todo";
import { getTodosByVisibilityFilter } from "../redux/selectors";
import { withStyles, withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const styles = {
  list: {
    border: "1px solid blue"
  }
};

const TodoList = React.forwardRef(
  ({ todos, theme, classes, location }, ref) => (
    <>
      <div>Location (from withRouter): {JSON.stringify(location)}</div>
      <div>theme.palette.primary.main: {theme.palette.primary.main}</div>
      <ul ref={ref} className={clsx("todo-list", classes.list)}>
        {todos && todos.length
          ? todos.map((todo, index) => {
              return <Todo key={`todo-${todo.id}`} todo={todo} />;
            })
          : "No todos, yay!"}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { visibilityFilter } = state;
  const todos = getTodosByVisibilityFilter(state, visibilityFilter);
  return { todos };
};
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
    null,
    { forwardRef: true }
  )(withTheme(withStyles(styles)(TodoList)))
);
```

`TodoApp.js`

```
import React from "react";
import AddTodo from "./components/AddTodo";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import VisibilityFilters from "./components/VisibilityFilters";
import "./styles.css";

export default function TodoApp() {
  const [renderIndex, incrementRenderIndex] = React.useReducer(
    prevRenderIndex => prevRenderIndex + 1,
    0
  );
  const todoListRef = React.useRef();
  const heightDisplayRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (todoListRef.current && heightDisplayRef.current) {
      heightDisplayRef.current.innerHTML = ` (height: ${
        todoListRef.current.offsetHeight
      })`;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <h1>
        Todo List
        <span ref={heightDisplayRef} />
      </h1>
      <AddTodo />
      <TodoList wrappedComponentRef={todoListRef} />
      <VisibilityFilters />
      <button onClick={incrementRenderIndex}>
        Trigger re-render of TodoApp
      </button>
      <div>Render Index: {renderIndex}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Todo App with Redux]

Comment: what if none of your components are classes and not functions. There are tons of examples for functions.

Comment: @mjwrazor I recommend that you create a separate question in order to more fully layout the specifics of your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use `compose` method and try something like this

```
const enhance = compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { forwardRef: true })
)
```

and use it before exporting component

```
export default enhance(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way! This will work for sure

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

//Just copy and add this withRouterAndRef HOC

const withRouterAndRef = (WrappedComponent) => {
class InnerComponentWithRef extends React.Component {    
      render() {
          const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
          return <WrappedComponent {...rest} ref={forwardRef} />;
      }
  }
  const ComponentWithRouter = withRouter(InnerComponentWithRef, { withRef: true });
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      return <ComponentWithRouter {...props} forwardRef={ref} />;
    });
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
}

//export using withRouterAndRef

export default withRouterAndRef (MyComponent)
```